# Working with a narrowed down DOM using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently trying to figure out a way to work within a selected `<div>` in order to be able to send a text formatted email.

So there is a button says "email". When a user clicks on it, it grabs a closest div as below.

```
var selectedDiv = $(callingElement).closest(".myClassName");
```

And from there I would like to grab various dom elements to create a clean text format. So how do I work within selectedDiv using jQuery?

For example,

1. Getting `<h1>` value.
2. Getting `<li>` value with certain class names
3. Getting "title" attribute value.

Comment: Consider keeping your data in a model of a MVC framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `selectedDiv` jQuery object wraps the `div` element. Use the `find` method to search for descendant elements, and `attr` to get the attributes on the `div` element itself.

```
selectedDiv.find('h1');
selectedDiv.find('li.someClass');
selectedDiv.attr('title');
```

Call the `text()` method to get the text from the `h1`, or the `li`.

```
selectedDiv.find('h1').text();
```

Comment: Providing the context is definitely more succinct, but I prefer `find` because it's more explicit.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy - I don't know how they compare in terms of performance, but jQuery will turn `$("selector", context)` into `$(context).find("selector")` internally. I would imagine `find` to be faster considering this, but I can't be sure without any benchmarks.

Comment: @Anurag I prefer terseness over explicitness. For instance, `$(fn)` over `$(document).ready(fn)`...

Answer (score 0):

```
selectedDiv.children('h1').text();
selectedDiv.children('li.className').text();
selectedDiv.attr('title');
```

But somehow I think you might be asking the "wrong" question.